# How do I reshape data to calculate ROC and AUC for binary text classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, auc

I'm very new to python and need to calculate the ROC and AUC of two binary classification models using NLP data. I can't seem to get my head around sparse vs dense arrays (I mean, I get that sparse arrays contain a ton of zeros, and dense arrays do not), data shape, and dimensionality.

I think I can produce pretty good preprocessed data, but inputting that into my classifiers in a way they can read has me stymied.

In my code below, you'll note that I have tried more than one train test split. I get

```
TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array.
```

if I don't convert x and y to dense.

I get

```
ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (1594, 286579) instead

UndefinedMetricWarning: No positive samples in y_true, true positive value should be meaningless
```

when I do the dense conversion.

And I get

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1594, 399]
```

when (if I'm remembering correctly) using the commented out train test split.

Here is my messy, redundant code:

```
import joblib
import re
import string
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, cohen_kappa_score, f1_score, classification_report
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold, train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

categories = ['rec.sport.baseball', 'rec.sport.hockey']

news_group_data = fetch_20newsgroups(subset="all", remove=("headers", "footers", "quotes"), categories=categories)

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(text=news_group_data["data"],target=news_group_data["target"]))
df["target"] = df.target.map(lambda x: categories[x])

def process_text(text):
    text = str(text).lower()
    text = re.sub(f"[{re.escape(string.punctuation)}]", " ", text)
    text = " ".join(text.split())
    return text

df["clean_text"] = df.text.map(process_text)

#df_train, df_test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.20, stratify=df.target)

vec = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 3), stop_words="english",)

x = vec.fit_transform(df.clean_text)
y = vec.transform(df.clean_text)


#X = vec.fit_transform(df_train.clean_text)
#Y = vec.transform(df_test.clean_text)

X = x.toarray()
Y = y.toarray()

#y_train = df_train.target
#y_test = df_test.target

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=.2,
                                                    random_state=0)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, ccp_alpha=0.0, class_weight=None,
                       criterion='gini', max_depth=None, max_features=5,
                       max_leaf_nodes=None, max_samples=None,
                       min_impurity_decrease=0.0, #min_impurity_split=None,
                       min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
                       min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=500,
                       n_jobs=None, oob_score=False, random_state=None,
                       verbose=0, warm_start=False)

nb = GaussianNB()
nb.fit(X_train, Y_train)

r_probs = [0 for _ in range(len(Y_test))]
rf_probs = rf.predict_proba(X_test)
nb_probs = nb.predict_proba(X_test)

rf_probs = rf_probs[:, 1]
nb_probs = nb_probs[:, 1]

from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, roc_auc_score

r_auc = roc_auc_score(Y_test, r_probs)
rf_auc = roc_auc_score(Y_test, rf_probs)
nb_auc = roc_auc_score(Y_test, nb_probs)

print('Random (chance) Prediction: AUROC = %.3f' % (r_auc))
print('Random Forest: AUROC = %.3f' % (rf_auc))
print('Naive Bayes: AUROC = %.3f' % (nb_auc))

r_fpr, r_tpr, _ = roc_curve(Y_test, r_probs)
rf_fpr, rf_tpr, _ = roc_curve(Y_test, rf_probs)
nb_fpr, nb_tpr, _ = roc_curve(Y_test, nb_probs)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(r_fpr, r_tpr, linestyle='--', label='Random prediction (AUROC = %0.3f)' % r_auc)
plt.plot(rf_fpr, rf_tpr, marker='.', label='Random Forest (AUROC = %0.3f)' % rf_auc)
plt.plot(nb_fpr, nb_tpr, marker='.', label='Naive Bayes (AUROC = %0.3f)' % nb_auc)

plt.title('ROC Plot')
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not using the correct target. You are basically encoding two times the text with the `CountVectorizer`, in these lines:

```
x = vec.fit_transform(df.clean_text)
y = vec.transform(df.clean_text)
```

Instead you should encode the binary class in df.target as target for the model (your `Y`)

```
def labeling(v):
    if v == categories[0]:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

df["target_encod"] = df.target.map(labeling)
print(df['target_encod'])
```

after that you can use the correct y for your machine learning problem

```
X = x.toarray()
Y = df["target_encod"].values
```

My result after the changes:

[image: AUROC]

For the next question, you forgot to assign a variable to the randomForest instance

```
RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, ccp_alpha=0.0, class_weight=None,
                   criterion='gini', max_depth=None, max_features=5,
                   max_leaf_nodes=None, max_samples=None,
                   min_impurity_decrease=0.0, #min_impurity_split=None,
                   min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
                   min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=500,
                   n_jobs=None, oob_score=False, random_state=None,
                   verbose=0, warm_start=False)
```

instead of

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, ccp_alpha=0.0, class_weight=None,
                   criterion='gini', max_depth=None, max_features=5,
                   max_leaf_nodes=None, max_samples=None,
                   min_impurity_decrease=0.0, #min_impurity_split=None,
                   min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
                   min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=500,
                   n_jobs=None, oob_score=False, random_state=None,
                   verbose=0, warm_start=False)
```

Comment: Thank you for sorting out the split, but I'm now getting "NameError: name 'rf' is not defined" from this section:

`
r_probs = [0 for _ in range(len(Y_test))]
rf_probs = rf.predict_proba(X_test)
nb_probs = nb.predict_proba(X_test)
`

What am I doing wrong there?

Comment: Actually, I spotted that as well just after sending again. However, when I run the code with that variable, I get this error: 

sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: This RandomForestClassifier instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.

I added a fit function like Naive Bayes has `rf.fit(X_train, Y_train)` and, though it took forever to run (I have an old computer), it did work. Thank you, Nikaido!